# CRUD DATABASE Using json source

Tags: json, datatables, crud

I have this .json source where the path is  `/my.json`:

```
{
"Aro":[
{
    "Name" : "Jhon",
    "Surname" : "Kenneth",
    "mobile" : 329129293,
    "email" : "jhon@gmail.com"  
},
{
    "Name" : "Jhon",
    "Surname" : "Kenneth",
    "mobile" : 329129293,
    "email" : "jhon@gmail.com"
},
{
    "Name" : "Jhon",
    "Surname" : "Kenneth",
    "mobile" : 329129293,
    "email" : "jhon@gmail.com"
}],
"Are":[
{
    "Name" : "Thor",
    "Surname" : "zvalk",
    "mobile" : 349229293,
    "email" : "thor@gmail.com"
},
{
    "Name" : "Thor",
    "Surname" : "zvalk",
    "mobile" : 349229293,
    "email" : "thor@gmail.com"
},
{
    "Name" : "Thor",
    "Surname" : "zvalk",
    "mobile" : 349229293,
    "email" : "thor@gmail.com"
},
]
}
```

I want to use it as a source in a CRUD database table in HTML.

This table is able to sporting, adding, editing, removing, updating...

Comment: I want it spry type from adobe

Answer (score 0):

You can use CRUD DataGrid with jQuery EasyUI

```
http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/app/crud2.php
```